# Cannot get json values from websocket message object

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

I'd like to receive messages from websocket connection and show them as push notifications, like this:

```
socket.onmessage = msg => {
  if( 'Notification' in window){
    if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
        doNotify(msg);
        });
    }
    else{
        Notification.requestPermission()
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);  //granted || denied
                if( Notification.permission == 'granted'){ 
                    doNotify();
                }
            })
            .catch( (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

}
};

function doNotify(msg) {
  console.log('msg to deal with  is:', msg) ;
  console.log('type of message: ', typeof msg);
  let msgJ = JSON.stringify(msg);
  console.log('msg in json format:', msgJ) ;
  console.log('type of msgJ: ', typeof msgJ);
  console.log('sender:', msgJ.data.sender) ;
  console.log(' body:', msgJ.data.body) ;

  let title = "Message from" +  msgJ.data.sender;
  let body = msgJ.data.body;
  let options = {
    title:  title,
    body:   body,
    vibrate: [100, 200, 100]
  }
  let n = new Notification(title, options);

}
```

However I'm seem to be unable to extract `title` and `body` from received messages.

Here are the console log results:

```
msg to deal with  is: MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "{"sender":"tomtom","body":"Hi there"}↵", origin: "ws://127.0.0.1:8080", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
type of message:  object
msg in json format: {"isTrusted":true}
type of msgJ:  string
socket.js?1579263492:52 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'sender' of undefined
    at doNotify (socket.js?1579263492:52)
    at socket.js?1579263492:17
```

What could be wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Your `data` comes as string `"{"sender":"tomtom","body":"Hi there"}"`. To get it deserialized I think your `data` should be like this `{"sender":"tomtom","body":"Hi there"}` , If that's not possible, then you have to deserialize the string itself into an object.

Comment: Well what I see is that the message is an objcet: `type of message:  object`.  Anyway I don't have control over the message coming from server. How can I extract the data from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageEvent.data` looks like a JSON string, as @chg already pointed out, so you need to convert it to an object.

```
let data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
let title = "Message from " +  data.sender;
```